# Can I add a column to an existing table without typing SQL commands in Adminer?

Tags: mysql, adminer

I administrate my MySQL database by Adminer 4.1.0. Now I wanted to add a column to an existing table and I didn't find how to do it except typing `ALTER TABLE` into the "SQL command" window. Lack of such a basic feature is not crippling for me (I know SQL enough), but still annoying. So did I miss something, or is SQL command window really the only way to add a column to an existing table in Adminer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Off course it is possible, just little hidden, took me some tie to find it. Click to the table, then "alter table" and then the plus (+) icon next to the column you want to add the new column after.

Comment: you answered your own question :) :) . By the way your answered helped me so thanks.

Comment: You answered your own question like you answered other person's question. lol.
But your answer was very helpful. thanks!

Comment: @MarkLozano There is even an option to ask a question and answer at the same time. I have never done that, but this is not my only case of the workflow "make some research - ask - in case of no answer do more research - find the solution - answer" :-) As long as you don't ommit the first step, it's ok.